# Program that compares files

Tags: python, spyder

So there has to be a program that compares 2 files and gives the compared result as the third file.

For example, one file is: `good`
And the second file is: `morning`
So the third would be: `good:morning`

I guess it has to be someone like this

```
    f1=open("file1.txt","r")
f2=open("file2.txt","r")
for line1 in f1:
    for line2 in f2:
        line1 + line2
```

what is it that I should do to get a result of the lines of 2 files together in a third file like in the example above?

Comment: there is a program that compares files, its called kdiff. That got nothing todo with python tho. Clarify your question. This way to broad.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (I did not check syntax):

```
with open("file1.txt","r") as f1:
    with open("file2.txt","r") as f2:
        for line1, line2 in zip(f1.readlines(), f2.readlines()):
            print(line1 + line2)
```

Comment: Thanks! can I just ask how would I use this sign ":" as a separator also without using print statements?

Comment: this works just perfect only needs this ":" as a separator between file lines as shown in the example and I am not supposed to use print statements

Comment: Im sure you'll figure it out. keyword is "string concatenation". Please don't forget to select my answer

Comment: but a file is not a string type, when i tried to concatenate it with ":" it didn;t work